# How can I limit my select statement to return only one row based on creation date?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How to limit my select statement to only show one ?

Comment: could you provide some test-data with a rextester link? like http://rextester.com/

Comment: @adamb - Can you simplify the question, as I ( guess not only me) get confused by the logic and the ranking system without some sample data.

Comment: alright, I'll try my best

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: What version of Oracle do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12c, you can use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT inactivationremark,
                    createts
              FROM t_se_internalrating ir
              WHERE ir.RATINGSTATUS = 'Deactivated'
              AND ir.PARTNERID = p1.ID
              ORDER BY ir.createts DESC
              fetch first 1 rows only
             ) ir
```

Look for CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY - this is the pattern you are looking for. [See here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9530807800346558418).

If you are using a lower version, you can use the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
inner join 
( SELECT 
       inactivationremark,
       createts,  
       row_number() OVER(
       PARTITION BY ir.partnerid ORDER BY ir.createts DESC)  rn
  FROM t_se_internalrating ir
  WHERE ir.ratingstatus = 'Deactivated') 
) ir
 ON ir.partnerid = p1.id AND ir.rn < 2
```

The `AND rn < 2` condition ensures that only the latest ratings are included.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11c

Comment: @adamb See the modified answer.

Comment: @adamb row_number() should be partitioned rather by  `ir.partnerid`, modified the answer